# Jackson - Serialize entity with self-reference

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "registry_entry")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class RegistryEntry extends GenericEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
  @JsonProperty("id")
  protected Long id;
  ...
  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(name = "srv_registry_entry_related_dependence",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_reg_entry", referencedColumnName = "id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_related_reg_entry", referencedColumnName = "id"))
  @JsonProperty
  private List<RegistryEntry> relatedRegistryEntries;
  ...
}
```

Assume that we have entities `A` and `B` where `B.relatedRegistryEntries` contains `A` and `A.relatedRegistryEntries` contains `B`.

When i try to serialize `A` or `B`, i get `StackOverflowError`. How can i serialize only id in this list?

Comment: probably you could use `@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "id")` above your class. Or you could write custom serializer above  your List class and annotate list with it `@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)` and `@JsonSerialize`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jackson supports [`@JsonIdentityInfo`](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureObjectIdentity). This is does what you're describing: adding this annotation to a class will make all instances of that class be serialized with an additional ID field, and the next time the same instance needs to be serialized the value of that ID field will be written instead of the whole object.

However, note that this is not standard JSON. In general, JSON format is usually used because it's widely supported by many libraries. Using this feature will likely create additional problems for your API clients.

The more universally compatible approach is to serialize the self-referenced object without its self-reference field:

```
public class RegistryEntry {
        @JsonIgnoreProperties("relatedRegistryEntries")
        private List<RegistryEntry> relatedRegistryEntries;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this annotatin to my class resolved my issue.

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "id")
```

I had a self referencing entity for which Jackson was going in infinite loop. 
While the property in issue was transient still Jakson was trying to serialize and giving issue.