# Jackson 2.14.3 set self references to null to prevent infinate rescurrsion

Tags: java, jackson

I'm attempting to reflect a java object into a map and leveraging Jackson 2.14.3 to accomplish this.  The jackson version is coming in via a maven transitive dependency.  I'm cannot use annotations as a remedy as the Object being passed through is unknown to this library.

Some of the objects contain JPA entities with bidirectional references.  I'm trying to use the serialization feature: `SerializationFeature.WRITE_SELF_REFERENCES_AS_NULL`, but it does not seem to have the result I was expecting (don't try and serialize the reference and set its value to `null` in the map).

I have tried using this feature with and without `SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_SELF_REFERENCES, false`.  When this setting is true (the default), I get the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle` , when false infinite recursion.

Can someone correct my understanding of the `SerializationFeature.WRITE_SELF_REFERENCES_AS_NULL` feature, or advise a configuration which can achieve my desired result?  Adding my current configuration below

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false); objectMapper.registerModule(new Hibernate5Module());
// objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_SELF_REFERENCES, false);
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_SELF_REFERENCES_AS_NULL, true);
Map<String, Object> m = objectMapper.convertValue(object, new TypeReference<>() {});
```

Comment: [Jackson - Serialize entity with self-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37388613/jackson-serialize-entity-with-self-reference) should help. But please stop serializing your entities and use DTOs instead (which is the accepted good practice), and there will be no problem in the first place.